# nonlinear integro-differential equation

Tags: differential, integro-differential-equations

I'm working on a engineering problem and I need to solve this nasty differential. I gave it a go with Laplace transforms, but no luck. Any ideas?
Note: a, b, c, and k are constants.

$$\frac{dm(t)}{dt}=\frac{a-b\cdot m(t)}{c\cdot t-\int_{t_i}^t m(x)\,dx}-k\cdot m(t)$$

Comment: What are the extremes of your integral? $\int m(x)\,dx$ makes no sense, in this context.

Comment: sorry, it would just be a 0 to t or ti to t

Comment: What happens if we set $M(t) = \int_{t_i}^t$, $dM/dt = m(t)$, $d^2M/dt^2 = dm/dt$, so now it's just a (sort of nasty looking) ODE.

Comment: Would you mind expanding upon just what engineering problem gave rise to this "rough beast"? (With apologies to W.B. Yeats.)

Comment: basically it describes the rate of change of a particular compound in the liquid phase of a system. Solid particles of this compound are experiencing convective mass transfer into the liquid (solid/liquid interface)  while the liquid phase is undergoing a bleed and feed at a constant volumetric flow rate.